# Can I add a code generation tool I wrote to my copy of Visual Studio as an extension?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, plugins, ado.net

I am writing a basic code generation tool.  It's pretty bare-bones and I am only doing it as a learning exercise and for messing around for fun, not for serious use.  It prompts you for a Class name and lets you add fields, specifying the name, type, whether it is a Primary Key, Foreign Key, nullable, a Collection type such as an array or Generic List, etc.  It creates a DTO class with Properties and if you check that it is a database table class, it also creates a DataAccess class (only things fully fleshed out with actual functional code that interacts with DB are GetByID, Insert, Update, Delete and an optional GetAll), a Business Logic Layer class with only pass through methods that call DataAccess class by default, a XAML and corresponding .cs class for both a details screen as well as a search screen with two-way model binding for all the field controls on the details screen.  It also creates the text for the Stored Procedures for all of the methods in the DataAccess class.

Is there a way for me to make the functionality I've described a plug-in for my copy of Visual Studio so I could use it on any of my projects I choose as I develop them from inside VS and have the generated classes automatically added to the solution?  I only want to use it for playing around, so I won't be too disappointed if this isn't possible.  Can this be done in Visual Studio by an average programmer?  I know I can finish my project in terms of code-generation functionality, except I'm more asking if it can be added to VS as a plug-in and what type of skills I would need to acquire to get it accomplished.  In particular, is it even possible for it to use the generated SP text to create actual SPs in the database from within a Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be possible, look at the visual studio SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk

However it would not be at all trivial.

Comment: I haven't done much C, C++, or Assembly Language since the nineties, can it be accomplished in C#?